# How to bind back unbinded divs

Tags: jquery

There is a spot in my code where I need a certain class (which attains to many divs) to be disabled from clicking.  So I found

```
$('.divClass').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

which works great. 
Now, after some loading functions, I need to bind all the divs back.
Please explain to me why this doesnt work:

```
 $('.divClass').attr('onclick','').bind('click');
```

How can I bind the divs back later on.

Comment: `$('.divClass').click(function(){// do something here})`

Comment: You need to bind some actions to the click event

Comment: what do I 'do' in order to enable clicking event for all divs again

Comment: I'd look to an alternative rather than unbinding the events.  Why are you unbinding?

Comment: I'll put an alternative solution below

Comment: Any reason why you're not using jquery's `$(selector).on('click', callback)` and `$(selector).off('click', callback)` syntax?

Comment: I wasnt sure what else to use, but I was informed .on .off is best practiced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually assign a function to your bind:

```
$(".divClass").bind("click", function() {
  // Something happens here
});
```

If you don't pass the function in you're not making the div do anything if clicked.

Full documentation for `bind` is here:
https://api.jquery.com/bind/

You should note that `bind` is considered to be obsolete as of jQuery 1.7+ and you should instead use `on`:

```
$(".divClass").on("click", function() {
  // Something happens here
});
```

Full documentation for `on` is here:
https://api.jquery.com/on/